# asp.net mvc get value from Model by Item Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, reflection, model

I have a requirement in which i want to pass item name and get value from Model like :

in my view model pass : 
@model atulitBaldhama.Models.webMaterial 
webMaterial Model has   column "Name"

```
@Model.Name
```

shows Name : it is ok

but now I want like :

```
@{
string columnName="Name"
}
@Model[columnName] OR @Model(columnName)
```

is it possible, if then how ?

please help

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
@Model.GetType().GetProperties()
          .Where(a=>a.Name==columnName).First().GetValue(Model, null)
```

Not particularly pretty but should work. You could look at using ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties instead.

Comment: thank, will it effect on performance like will it slow reading from db?

Comment: reflection is notorious for being inefficient but compared with your full call it will probably be fine as you're not doing too much.  as ever measure the time and see for yourself.  also beware of trying to over-optimise where you don't need to.  it will not affect read from db but add a couple of milliseconds after that.

Comment: it's customary to says thanks through upvoting and accepting answer ;)